# jQuery function not working after another function runs

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have two jquery functions, one for following, and one for unfollowing, and when you click either of them, they change to the opposite word. The thing is, if you click "Follow", it changes to "Unfollow" like it should, but then you can't click the link again unless you refresh. Here are my functions:

```
$(function(){
    $('#follow').on('click',function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url : 'functions/follow.php',
            data: {follower : $.upnamespace.session_id,
                   user : $.upnamespace.p_id},
            success: function(result) {
                if(result == 'followed'){
                    $('#follow').attr('id','unfollow').text('-Unfollow');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
$(function(){
    $('#unfollow').on('click',function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url : 'functions/unfollow.php',
            data: {follower : $.upnamespace.session_id,
                   user : $.upnamespace.p_id},
            success: function(result) {
                if(result == 'unfollowed'){
                    $('#unfollow').attr('id','follow').text('+Follow');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here is one of the links, the other is the same except for the ID being "unfollow" and the text being "-Unfollow"

```
<a id="follow" class="small button blue" style="color:#fff">+Follow</a>
```

Comment: You should never modificate attribute id of a specific element. This is just calling for issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As unfollow doesn't exist initially , you need to use event delegation

```
$(document).on('click','#unfollow',function(){
```

- http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: But then click on #follow will trigger click on delegate of #unfollow too  http://jsfiddle.net/W5cvK/

Comment: _"you need to"_ - Well no, you don't _need_ to, but that is _one_ way to fix it as long as you apply the same change to the other click handler too.

Answer (score 2):

You can shorten your code like this and you won't need to change the `ID`

```
$(function(){
    $('#follow').on('click',function(){
        var url = $(this).text() == '+Follow' ? 'functions/follow.php' : 'functions/unfollow.php';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url : url,
            data: {follower : $.upnamespace.session_id, user : $.upnamespace.p_id},
            success: function(result) {
                if(result == 'unfollowed'){
                    $('#follow').text('+Follow');
                } else if(result == 'followed') {
                    $('#follow').text('-Unfollow');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think changing the `id` property is the best solution.

Try something like

```
$(function(){
    $('#follow').on('click',function(){
        var $this = $(this), type = $this.data('followType') || 'follow', follow = type == 'follow';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url : 'functions/' + follow + '.php',
            data: {follower : $.upnamespace.session_id,
                   user : $.upnamespace.p_id},
            success: function(result) {
                if(result == 'followed'){
                    $this.text('-Unfollow').data('followType', 'unfollow');
                } else if(result == 'unfollowed'){
                    $this.text('+Follow').data('followType', 'follow');;
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```